# Error importing Swagger 2.0 Definition on SoapUI 5.2.0

Tags: api, soapui, swagger

I'm getting an error (java.util.NoSuchElementException) importing a Swagger 2.0 definition on SoapUI 5.2.0.  Does anyone know how I can import the swagger json to SoapUI or why this error is displayed?  I've also tried loading on Ready! API 1.3.1 which produced the same error.

**Steps to recreate**

- Create a new empty project
- Right Click on the project and select
  Import Swagger
- Enter the Swagger Definition (.json) for Definition
  Type: Resource Listing Click OK

**Results**

Some definitions are loaded, but then an error is displayed.
java.util.NoSuchElementException

**Here is a copy of the error log**

```
Fri Jul 24 08:28:39 CDT 2015:ERROR:java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java_util_Iterator$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.smartbear.swagger.Swagger2Importer$_addOperation_closure3.doCall(Swagger2Importer.groovy:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3875)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1354)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$149.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callSafe(AbstractCallSite.java:82)
    at com.smartbear.swagger.Swagger2Importer.addOperation(Swagger2Importer.groovy:164)
    at com.smartbear.swagger.Swagger2Importer$addOperation.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at com.smartbear.swagger.Swagger2Importer.importPath(Swagger2Importer.groovy:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:361)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at com.smartbear.swagger.Swagger2Importer$_importSwagger_closure1.doCall(Swagger2Importer.groovy:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3875)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1354)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$149.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.smartbear.swagger.Swagger2Importer.importSwagger(Swagger2Importer.groovy:67)
    at com.smartbear.swagger.SwaggerImporter$importSwagger.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.smartbear.swagger.SwaggerUtils$1.construct(SwaggerUtils.groovy:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:46)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Try this: http://www.soapui.org/support/support-overview.html